# Primeng create, update not working with checkboxes

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using angular 7 and primeng

When I am trying to use Primeng CRUD application with checkboxes , I am getting various errors while checking/unchecking primeng  checkboxes

When I am checking checkboxes intially everything is working fine..but when I once call save  or delete records I am getting errors like

```
TypeError: this.selection.filter is not a function
    at Table.push../node_modules/primeng/components/table/table.js.Table.toggleRowWithCheckbox (table.js:851)
    at TableCheckbox.push../node_modules/primeng/components/table/table.js.TableCheckbox.onClick (table.js:3120)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (TableCheckbox.html:2)
    at handleEvent (core.js:23008)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24078)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23805)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:20457)
    at core.js:20904
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)


    TypeError: this.selection.concat is not a function
    at Table.push../node_modules/primeng/components/table/table.js.Table.toggleRowWithCheckbox (table.js:859)
    at TableCheckbox.push../node_modules/primeng/components/table/table.js.TableCheckbox.onClick (table.js:3120)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (TableCheckbox.html:2)
    at handleEvent (core.js:23008)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24078)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23805)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:20457)
    at core.js:20904
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
```

Here is my code , I am using a component 
this is my html file

```
<p-table #warddt [columns]="cols" [value]="wards"  [(selection)]="selectedWard" 
 [paginator]="true" [rows]="5" [lazy]="false" 
 [pageLinks]="5"  [totalRecords]="totalRecordsCount" [responsive]="true" [loading] = "loading"
  (onLazyLoad)="loadWardsLazy($event)" dataKey="title"> 


    <ng-template pTemplate="caption">


            <div style="text-align:right">
                    <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-plus" (click)="showDialogToAdd()" label="Create Ward"></button>
                </div>

      Wards List
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      <tr>
            <th style="width: 3em">
                    <p-tableHeaderCheckbox [value] = "ward" ></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
         </th>
          <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
              {{col.header}}
              <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
          </th>
          <th>
                Action
            </th>
      </tr>
    <!-- filters code -->
    <tr>
            <th style="width: 3em">

         </th>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field">
            <input *ngSwitchCase="'title'" pInputText type="text" (input)="warddt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)">
            <input *ngSwitchCase="'code'" pInputText type="text" (input)="warddt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)">
            <input *ngSwitchCase="'head_name'" pInputText type="text" (input)="warddt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)">
            <input *ngSwitchCase="'location'" pInputText type="text" (input)="warddt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)">
        </th>
        <th style="width: 3em">

            </th>
    </tr>
    <!-- end filters code -->
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
      <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
            <td>
                    <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"></p-tableCheckbox>
            </td>
          <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
              {{rowData[col.field]}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
                <a style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="action(rowData, 'edit')" class="ui-g-2">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <span class="ui-g-2">|</span>
                <a style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="action(rowData, 'Delete')" class="ui-g-2">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="summary" >
        <ul >
            <li *ngFor="let ward of selectedWard" style="text-align: left">
                 {{ward.title + ' - ' + ward.code + ' - ' + ward.location + ' - ' + ward.head_name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ng-template>

</p-table>

<p-dialog header="Ward Details" [(visible)]="displayDialog" [responsive]="true" 
showEffect="fade" [modal]="true"  [style]="{width: '300px'}">
  <div class="ui-g ui-fluid" *ngIf="createWard">
      <div class="ui-g-12">
          <div class="ui-g-4">
              <label for="vin">Ward No.</label>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-g-8">
              <input pInputText id="vin" [(ngModel)]="createWard.title" />
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-12">
          <div class="ui-g-4">
              <label for="year">Ward Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-g-8">
              <input pInputText id="year" [(ngModel)]="createWard.code" />
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-12">
          <div class="ui-g-4">
              <label for="brand">Location</label>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-g-8">
              <input pInputText id="brand" [(ngModel)]="createWard.location" />
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-12">
          <div class="ui-g-4">
              <label for="color">Ward Head Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-g-8">
              <input pInputText id="color" [(ngModel)]="createWard.head_name" />
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <p-footer>
      <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-helper-clearfix">
          <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-close" (click)="deleteWard()" label="Delete"></button>
          <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-check" (click)="saveWard()" label="Save"></button>
      </div>
  </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

.ts file code is

```
export class WardComponent implements OnInit {
  totalRecords: number;
  loading: boolean;
  wardFilterModel: any;
  wardListing: any;
  createWard: WardInterface;
  constructor(public rest: WardService, private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router, private messageService: MessageService,
              private jsonWardsService: JsonWardsService, public http: HttpClient,
              private alertService: AlertService) { }

  displayDialog: boolean;
  ward: any;
  selectedWard: WardInterface;
  newWard: boolean;
  wards: WardInterface[];
  cols: any = {};
  wardItems: any;
  JsonWards: any;


  ngOnInit() {


    this.cols = [
    { field: 'title', header: 'Ward No' },
    { field: 'code', header: 'Ward Name' },
    { field: 'location', header: 'Location' },
    { field: 'head_name', header: 'Ward Head Name' },
];

    this.loading = true;
  }


  showDialogToAdd() {
    this.newWard = true;
    this.ward = {};
    this.displayDialog = true;
}


saveWard() {
  if (Object.keys(this.createWard).length === 0 ||
  this.createWard.title === undefined ||
  this.createWard.code === undefined ||
  this.createWard.location === '' ||
  this.createWard.head_name === ''
) {
  this.alertService.showMessage('Please fill required details', '', MessageSeverity.error);
} else {
    const wards = [...this.wards];
    if (this.newWard) {
        wards.push(this.ward);
        this.alertService.showMessage('Ward Created Successfully!', this.ward.data, MessageSeverity.success);
    } else {
        wards[this.wards.indexOf(this.selectedWard)] = this.createWard;
        this.alertService.showMessage('Ward Updated Successfully!', this.selectedWard.code, MessageSeverity.success);
    }
    this.wards = wards;
  // this.ward = null;
    this.displayDialog = false;
  }

}

deleteWard() {
    const index = this.wards.indexOf(this.selectedWard);
    this.wards = this.wards.filter((val, i) => i !== index);
    this.ward = null;
    this.displayDialog = false;
    this.alertService.showMessage('Ward Deleted Successfully!', this.selectedWard.code, MessageSeverity.success);
}

action(data: WardInterface, type: string) {
  this.selectedWard  = data;
  this.newWard = false;
  this.createWard = this.cloneWard(data);
  this.displayDialog = true;
}


cloneWard(c: WardInterface): WardInterface {
    const ward = {};
    for (const prop in c) {
        ward[prop] = c[prop];
    }
    return ward;
}

}
```

This is my interface code which I am using..

```
export interface WardInterface {
id?;
tenent_id?;
language_id?;
title?;
code?;
head_name?;
location?;
remark?;
active?;
created_by?;
}
```

Can anyone help me with same.. Let me know if anything else required.

Comment: in the html you iterate with an ngFor over selectedWard, but it is not an array it is an object, this could be one problem, I will still looking at your ode to find what could be wrong...

Comment: @octavio Yes.. this can be problem.. but i have already tried declared selectedWard as array . Morever when i remove that Html chunk from code.. then also I get same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to you not having specified the selectionMode on your table

i.e.

```
selectionMode="multiple"
```